# Invalid date: 01-Jan-2055

Tags: time-date

I recently downloaded Emacs 24.4 and sometimes I see an "invalid date" error in my buffer.

When I am in `eww`, often I try to click (`RET`) a link and I get:

```
error in process sentinel: Invalid date: 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00.00 GMT
```

I thought it was an eww error, but today I was in `c-mode` and I saw

```
Error running timer `url-cookie-write-file': (error "Invalid date: 01-Jan-2055 00:00:00.00 GMT")
```

How can I fix this? I've not found any useful post with an "invalid date".
Thanks!

Comment: Find out what code you have loaded invokes function `url-cookie-write-file` from a timer. Use `grep`. Or bisect your init file recursively until you narrow it down to the culprit code.

Comment: Or use `toggle-debug-on-error`, it should give you a backtrace which will tell you where this function is called.

Comment: Emacs knows something that we don't.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/punchagan/org2blog/issues/176

punchagan writes:

> This bug seems to have been fixed on Emacs master. As a work around you could add the latest code of url-cookie-expired-p to your .emacs

```
(defun url-cookie-expired-p (cookie)
  "Return non-nil if COOKIE is expired."
  (let ((exp (url-cookie-expires cookie)))
    (and (> (length exp) 0)
     (condition-case ()
         (> (float-time) (float-time (date-to-time exp)))
       (error nil)))))
```